# How to change an Excel border through C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, border

The following code is properly compiled but then no border appears.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
  app.Visible = true;
  app.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
  Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
  Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];

  //BORDERS HERE
  ws.Range["A1:C5"].Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
  ws.Range["A1:C5"].Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Weight = 10d;
  ws.Range["A1:C5"].Borders.ColorIndex = XlRgbColor.rgbCrimson;
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: This relates to WPF how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `BeginUpdateFormatting` method for this range, modify `Borders` and call the `EndUpdateFormatting` method to finalize the modification.

```
Range range = ws.Range["A1:C5"];
Formatting rangeFormatting = range.BeginUpdateFormatting();
Borders rangeBorders = rangeFormatting.Borders;
rangeBorders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
rangeBorders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Weight = 10d;
rangeBorders.ColorIndex = XlRgbColor.rgbCrimson;
range.EndUpdateFormatting(rangeFormatting);
```